# cuda invalid Configuration argument

Tags: cuda

I am trying to launch a kernel with some params that I believe a valid but am receiving the invalid configuration argument error.

I am setting the sizes like this:

```
dim3 BlockDim = dim3(128, 1, 1);
dim3 GridDim  = dim3(321, 320, 1);
```

and then launching my kernel

```
kernel<<<BlockDim,GridDim>>>();
```

My understanding is that this should be fine.
From device query I get:

```
Device 0: "Tesla C1060"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          6.0 / 5.5
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    1.3
  Total amount of global memory:                 4096 MBytes (4294770688 bytes)
  (30) Multiprocessors x (  8) CUDA Cores/MP:    240 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                1296 MHz (1.30 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             800 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              512-bit
  Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)             1D=(8192), 2D=(65536,32768), 3D=(2048,2048,2048)
  Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers        1D=(8192) x 512, 2D=(8192,8192) x 512
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       16384 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 16384
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  1024
  Maximum number of threads per block:           512
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    512 x 512 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     65535 x 65535 x 1
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             256 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      No
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           66 / 0
  Compute Mode:
```

Am I missing something here?

A few more tests I have run:

Works

```
dim3 BlockDim = dim3(128, 1, 1);
dim3 GridDim  = dim3(200, 1, 1);
```

Does not work

```
dim3 BlockDim = dim3(128, 1, 1);
dim3 GridDim  = dim3(30001, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

I had blockDim and gridDim reversed in my kernel call.

Should have been:

```
kernel<<<GridDim,BlockDim>>>();
```